# Discord bot command shop not working (sqlite3, Discord.py)

Tags: python, sqlite, discord.py

I'm trying to implement a store on my Discord server, but the command is not executed also there are no errors in the console, this code was translated to sqlite 3 with JSON,
I'm new to sqlite 3 and Discord.py

```
@client.command( pass_context = True )
async def buy(ctx, arg = None):
    role = arg
    if role == None:
        await ctx.send("**Укажите роль, которую хотите купить.**")

    Aqua=50000
    Red=100000
    Green=150000
    Blue=200000
    Pink=250000
    Gold=500000

    Aqua_role = discord.utils.get( ctx.message.guild.roles, id = 718214683454210088)
    Red_role = discord.utils.get( ctx.message.guild.roles, id = 718215132286550046)
    Green_role = discord.utils.get( ctx.message.guild.roles, id = 718215275618631681)
    Blue_role = discord.utils.get( ctx.message.guild.roles, id = 718216550959677712)
    Pink_role = discord.utils.get( ctx.message.guild.roles, id = 718215775504171049)
    Gold_role = discord.utils.get( ctx.message.guild.roles, id = 718215931406581801)

    async def shop_buy(ctx):
        for row in cursor.execute(f"SELECT money FROM users where id={ctx.author.id}"):

            if role == "Gold":
                if gold_role in ctx.author.roles:
                    await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, у вас уже имеется роль {Gold_role}")


                elif row[0] >= Gold:
                    balance = row[0] - summ

                    await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(                           
                        description=f" {ctx.author.mention}, покупка прошла успешно ",
                        colour=0x00ff00
                    ))

                    cursor.execute(f'UPDATE users SET money={balance} where id={ctx.author.id}')
                    conn.commit()
                    await ctx.author.add_roles(Gold_role) 

                else:
                    await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(                     
                        description=f"**{ctx.message.author.mention}, такой суммы нет у вас на баллансе!**",
                        colour=0xff0000
                        ))
```

Comment: Please don't use string formatting/concatenation for passing values to SQL queries. It is prone to error and SQL injection. Instead use your driver's placeholders and pass the arguments separately to `execute()`. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html for how to use `?` in case of SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually running the `shop_buy()` coroutine anywhere, you've only defined it. Functions/coroutines won't run unless you call them.

The coroutine isn't even necessary if you're only going to be using the code in one place anyway.

You can also define the `shop_buy()` coroutine outside of the command if you want to use it in another place:

```py
@client.command() # context is automatically passed in rewrite
async def buy(ctx, arg = None):
    role = arg
    if role == None:
        await ctx.send("**Укажите роль, которую хотите купить.**")

    Aqua=50000
    Red=100000
    Green=150000
    Blue=200000
    Pink=250000
    Gold=500000

    Aqua_role = discord.utils.get( ctx.message.guild.roles, id = 718214683454210088)
    Red_role = discord.utils.get( ctx.message.guild.roles, id = 718215132286550046)
    Green_role = discord.utils.get( ctx.message.guild.roles, id = 718215275618631681)
    Blue_role = discord.utils.get( ctx.message.guild.roles, id = 718216550959677712)
    Pink_role = discord.utils.get( ctx.message.guild.roles, id = 718215775504171049)
    Gold_role = discord.utils.get( ctx.message.guild.roles, id = 718215931406581801)

    async def shop_buy(ctx):
        # shop_buy() code here

    await shop_buy(ctx) # you need to call the coroutine
```

Comment: Thank you very much, now I understand my mistake :)

Comment: No worries! If you found the answer useful, go ahead and [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it, as it could help other people that have the same issue. Good luck with your bot! Happy coding :^)